# I need help identifying a completely unknown plant for my biology class

Tags: botany, species-identification

I know two things about this plant 
1 is that it does not need to be watered for a long time because it has been able to survive in my schools greenhouse for quite some time without water and 2 my teacher says she "thinks" it blooms purple or pink flowers. 
Thank you in advance for any help given!

[image: plant]

Comment: Appears to be a succulent of some sort?

Comment: Any information on where it's native to?

Comment: "Succulent plant" means any plants that stores water inside their thickened  body-tissue. btw "succulent" is Not a "taxonomic-group" like "phanerogams", "cryptogams" etc. Succulents found in different-groups of plants. It is one-sort of adaptation against dryness. So, many desert plants  are succulent in nature.

Answer (score 4):

I'm no expert on plants but it could be a [kalanchoe](http://www.todayshomeowner.com/how-to-grow-flowering-kalanchoe/). That's based mainly on the leaf characteristics and size.

[image]

There's some 120 or so species mainly originating from the old world. These are quite [drought tolerant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalanchoe) as yours seems to be. They are a common houseplant and there are ways to [stimulate reflowering](http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/kalanchoe/make-a-kalanchoe-rebloom.htm) so that also makes it a good candidate.

[Image source](http://nature.jardin.free.fr/succulente/ft_kalanchoe_blos.html).

Comment: Awesome!! How is this done? Do you just happen to know them or you enter the characters or something in a key? Like, what is the std approach when you have no clue and youve got to identify?

Comment: @rg255 - JMusser will not get the ping unless he's posted in the thread. You might want to ping him in chat.

Comment: @Polisetty just persistence and searches!

Comment: Looks like a Kalanchoe to me, too! To answer @Polisetty 's question, you might go about identifying this by noting that it is a succulent ('juicy' leaves and does not need to be watered frequently), that it's opposite-leaved, that the leaf margins are jagged (I suppose maybe 'crenate' specifically), and that it has red flowers. This isn't going to help you much in using a botanical key, but might give you a start in google image-searching...

Comment: I was thinking of *Sedum spectabile*, another member of the *Crassulaceae*. But maybe *Kalanchoe* is better. @Polisetty Try to make it flower!